# Правильно ли я использую AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Первый раз работаю с `AsyncTask` вроде все сделал, но такое чувство что, что-то не учел... Я новичок...

**Вот код :**

```
public class AsyncCheckABC extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnKeyListener {
private int finish;
private int mistake;
private int number;
private boolean stopWhile;
private Context context;
private Chronometer chronometer;
private ImageView ivLetter;
private List<Letters> array;
private EditText etInputLatter;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_check_yourself);
    context = this;
    array = com.example.tanya_.learnhebrew.singeltons.Letters.getInstance().getLetterses();
    etInputLatter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAddLetter);
    ivLetter = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivLetter);
    ivLetter.setImageResource(R.drawable.krokosha);

    etInputLatter.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                checkYourself();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    return false;
}

private void startChronometer() {
    chronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
    chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    chronometer.start();
}

public void checkYourself(View v) {
    checkYourself();
}

private void checkYourself() {
    String inputLatter = etInputLatter.getText().toString();
    String vvodSKlavi = array.get(number).getVvodSKlavi();

    if (inputLatter.isEmpty())
        Toast.makeText(context, "enter you answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else {
        if (vvodSKlavi.equals(inputLatter)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "you are right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            etInputLatter.setText("");
            finish += 1;
            this.stopWhile = true;
        }
        if (!inputLatter.equals(vvodSKlavi)) {
            mistake += 1;
            Toast.makeText(context, "try one more", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            etInputLatter.setText("");
        }
    }
}

public void startCheck(View v) {
    etInputLatter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.check).setEnabled(true);
    findViewById(R.id.bStart).setEnabled(false);
    startCheck();
}

private void startCheck() {
    MyAsync async = new MyAsync();
    async.execute();
}

private class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    private long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    private int[] mesInitializing(int arraySize) {
        int[] mes = new int[arraySize];
        for (int i = 0; i < mes.length; i++) {
            mes[i] = -1;
        }
        return mes;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        startChronometer();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        int[] mes = mesInitializing(array.size());

        boolean check = true;
        finish = 0;
        int i = 0;

        while (finish < array.size()) {

            number = (int) (Math.random() * array.size());

            for (int obj : mes) {
                check = number != obj;
                if (!check) break;
            }

            if (check) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ivLetter.setImageResource(
                                array.get(number).getIdIRForPropis());
                    }
                });

                mes[i] = number;
                i += 1;
                while (!stopWhile) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                stopWhile = false;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);

        final long totalTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(totalTime);
        final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");

        chronometer.stop();
        ivLetter.setImageDrawable(null);
        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        etInputLatter.setText(" ");

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AsyncCheckABC.this);
        builder.setTitle("Results!")
                .setMessage("Your mistake " + mistake + "\n" + " Your time " +
                        format.format(cal.getTime()) + "\n" + "Do you want try again?")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.goodresult)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setNegativeButton("I want try again!",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                startCheck();
                            }
                        })
                .setPositiveButton("Cancel ",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                                finish();
                            }
                        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}

public void backToABC(View v) {
    finish();
}
}
```

Может что то нужно поправить? Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: `MyAsync` имеет ссылку на `AsyncCheckABC`. Как Вы думаете, что будет если, например, покрутить устройство? ;)

Comment: Сорри, я вообще не понял вопроса... "'MyAsync' имеет ссылку на 'AsyncCheckABC'" - где?  И что значит покрутить устройство? Куда?

Comment: Я не могу показать ссылку, так как она не явная. Под покрутить я имел ввиду смену ориентации экрана, как частный случай configuration changes.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем вы используете поток в AsynkTask ? Если вы хотите менять image, то переопределите метод onProgressUpdate() в AsynkTask, а в doInBackground выполняйте команду publishProgress, после вызова этой команды вызывается метод onProgressUpdate();